# frontend image post uploader

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, images, uploads

I've set up image uploader on front end custom form for users with some text input, textareas etc .Everything works fine, untill I decide don't upload any image.

Then my "thank you" page gets blank. No head data, no body content just

```
 <html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Here's the code

```
  //SAVE THE POST
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
    if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
        }
         if (!empty($_FILES)) {
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                   return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];

               }
                $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $pid );
            }          
     }
     if ($attach_id > 0){
            //and if you want to set that image as Post  then use:
            update_post_meta($pid,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
        }
```

I think It is related with image uploader validation, becouse when I deleted that part

```
   if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
               return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
```

It redirects me to "thank you" page and displays everything well, but in admin posts in thumbnail box I receive

```
     Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in
```

But ther is nothing to be converted, becouse I didn't upload anything...

Can anyone help me with this one :) ?